# How long does it take for zerglings to spawn during 6-pool and 7-pool in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, sc2-build-order

I'm interested in the time from start to when the first 6 zerglings spawn for the 6 and 7 pool rush. Is the 6-pool significantly faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on these two videos: [7pool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_O-wVxp4p_A) and [6pool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rBfbj-ujsU)

The timing seem to be:

- 7 Pool: 1:20
- 6 Pool: 1:35

Note: these values are in Real Time, not Game Time.

Based on your skill your results may very.

Comment: Looking at the videos it seems to be 2:20 gametime for 6-pool and 2:30 for 7-pool so there seems to be no significant difference and if the rush fails 6-pool leaves you with a slightly weaker economy.

Comment: Again there is a difference between gametime and realtime.  The numbers I posted are for a player playing the game.  An in game replay will show different numbers as gametime is faster